# Where can I configure the browser behavior of Playwright in VSCode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, playwright

I'm starting to use Playwright with VSCode.
I have it running from Test in VSCode, but the browser is not showing up. I would like to get the browser to show up, but where can I configure the browser behavior?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure exactly if by "browser to show up" you refer at the fact that you need the browser to not run in headless mode.

There are two possible ways:

1. Install [Playwright Test for VSCode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-playwright.playwright) as suggest by @MingJie-MSFT. You'll have a Show browser checkbox there in case you want to run your tests headless or not
2. In the config file, for use, add:

> headless: false

[Example for both options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3pV8.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please install [Playwright Test for VSCode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-playwright.playwright) extension which automatically detects if you have Playwright installed and loads the browsers.

[image]